# Juno debugger in Atom - Numerous problems interacting with debug session, like ArgumentError invalid index, UndefVarError, etc

Tags: debugging, julia, atom-editor, juno-ide

I am trying to use the debugger that comes with JuliaPro 1.2.0-1. This collection of software provides an IDE (Atom) and a debugger ("Juno", or something).

A create a new `.jl` file containing only

```
function test()
    a = 1
    b = 2
end
```

And put a breakpoint on line 2, `a=1`.

I then either copy and paste it into the REPL (interactive julia pane), or select the code and hit Ctrl+Enter to do the same.

Now `test()` is defined in the REPL session. I then open the debugger. Now everything looks like below:

[image]

After a lot of trouble with poor documentation, I figured out how to start the debugging session by executing `Juno.@enter test()` in the REPL window. I do so, and it hits the breakpoint supposedly:

[image]

I then want to to interact with the variables inside `test()`. Such as calling `print(a)`. It prints, but then some weird error occurs:

[image]

If I just type `a`, I get:

[image]

[Supposedly](https://julialang.org/blog/2019/03/debuggers) `c` and `fm` are commands in the debug session, but they don't work.

[image]

So I'm completely confused. Is the debugger broken? Am I using it incorrectly? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. `JuliaPro` simply doesn't have a working debugger. There is some conflict or outdated versions of the packages, causing the above problems.

I uninstalled `JuliaPro`, and instead installed `julia`, `Atom` text editor, and finally `Juno` through the text editor using [this guide](http://docs.junolab.org/latest/man/installation/). Now `print(a)` and `a` both work as expected in the `debug>` session. However commands `c` and `fm` still don't work, and I'm not sure why (edit: see @pfitzseb comment).

Comment: Those commands aren't supposed to work in Juno's debugger, which is different from [Debugger.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDebug/Debugger.jl) (although that also doesn't support a `fm` command). See [here](http://docs.junolab.org/latest/man/debugging/) for a quick tutorial on how to debug code in Juno.